# Renaming a project configuration in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ide

I've got the good fortune to be stuck in Visual C++ 6 (don't laugh at me too hard), and the project I'm working on makes use of many different build configurations. While I guess I can create the new configuration manually by modifying the `.dsp` file, I'd really rather not do that out of fear that I's miss something. I don't know enough about this ancient codebase to make a new configuration from scratch, and unfortunately (ok, maybe fortunately) everybody who's ever worked on this code was either fired or quit.

Anyway, I'd like to rename some of the project configurations so that I can copy them and make a new one based off of them. This will all make sense in a second (maybe someone can suggest another idea as well).

[image]

As you can see, the old project configuration names are too long for the combo box; and too similar for me to distinguish between them. Unfortunately, the combobox is not expandable and has no tooltips; so I'm taking a stab in the dark when selecting a configuration to copy settings from.

So I was thinking, if I could figure out how to rename the ones I want to copy from, I can stick a stray character in front of them so that I can distinguish them from each other, but alas I can't even figure out how to do that.

Comment: While it might be tricky to clone a configuration by directly editing .dsp file, it shouldn't be difficult to rename an existing configuration by doing so. It's a text file, just Find and Replace (save a backup copy first, of course).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah, that's ultimately what I decided to do. I was just hoping there was a better way, oh well.